# Difference between c++ functions 'remainder' and 'fmod'?

Tags: c++, c++11

Recently I came across the need to use `fmod()` function in C++ to calculate modulus of two long double operands.

But I also saw that there is some **"remainder"** function in C++ that does almost the same job.

What is the difference between those two functions?

Comment: Did you look this up before posting?  http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/remainder

Comment: @OliCharlesworth i did. But i got confused with different answers.

Answer (score 10):

The `remainder()` function in C++ computes the floating-point remainder of numerator/denominator (rounded to nearest).

**`remainder (x, y)` = x - rquote * y**

where rquote is the result of x/y, rounded towards the nearest integral value (with halfway cases rounded towards the even number).

Another hand, The `fmod()` function in C++ computes the floating-point remainder of numerator/denominator (rounded towards zero).

**`fmod (x, y)` = x - tquote * y**

where tquote is truncated i.e. (rounded towards zero) result of x/y.

Example

```
double x = 7.5, y = 2.1;
double result = remainder(x, y);// output is -0.9 
double result2 = fmod(x, y);// output is 1.2
```

Answer (score 5):

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/remainder:

> In contrast to `std::fmod()`, the returned value is not guaranteed to have the same sign as `x`.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to put it:

`std::remainder(x,y)` will always return between [-y/2, y/2],

`std::fmod(x,y)` will return either [0, abs(y)] or [-abs(y), 0], depends on the sign of x.

Answer (score 2):

fmod calculates as "These functions compute the remainder from the division of numerator by denominator. Specifically, the return value is numerator - n * denominator, where n is the quotient of numerator divided by denominator, rounded towards zero to an integer"

reminder calculates as "These functions are like fmod except that they round the internal quotient n to the nearest integer instead of towards zero to an integer"